# differences between org.jboss.redhat-fuse/fabric8-maven-plugin and io.fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm using org.jboss.redhat-fuse/fabric8-maven-plugin in one my project but somehow the latest version is always behind.

Is there any reason why we are encouraged to use org.jboss.redhat-fuse/fabric8-maven-plugin for RH Fuse project? instead of io.fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of `io.fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin`.

[`org.jboss.redhat-fuse/fabric8-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fabric8-maven-plugin) is Jboss's fork of upstream fabric8 maven plugin i.e [`io.fabric8/fabric8-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin). Jboss's fork may contain some jboss related patches as per it's requirements. I think it is used under FUSE internals like for Fuse Online. Usually it's synced with upstream plugin from time to time.

If you want to use plugin as a general purpose Kubernetes/Openshift plugin. I recommend to use upstream Fabric8 Maven Plugin. If you are working around FUSE related stuff, then maybe go with Jboss's fork since it's tried and tested. But I think upstream would also work fine.

Comment: Hi, i am using fuse and i have tested the replacement with your plugin, it seems compatible, i would rather use yours where it is more updated. Thanks!